# Why is my search box not quite the same size as my button within the same div? Taller by 1-2px. Also why don't the font sizes match?

Tags: css

See demo and source CSS+HTML (via view source) at http://arcane-earth-5322.herokuapp.com/

Driving me nuts trying to get the button and search box to be the exact same height, same position (horizontally aligned) and same font. I have got it close, but no cigar.

Zoom in 200% to see the difference in height. The search box is 1-2px taller and looks to be fractionally lower on the page.

I also don't understand why the computed font sizes for the button and search box are different at most zoom levels (inc. 100%).

**EDIT**: Adding the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
      <title>Responsive Test</title>
      <style  type="text/css">
         body {
         color:#555;
         font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
         font-size:110%;
         line-height:140%;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         -moz-background-size:cover;
         -webkit-background-size:cover;
         background-size:cover;
         background:url(http://d7mj4aqfscim2.cloudfront.net/images/landscapes/duo-land_mv_c9ad01b8dcb245a1140bd5cb57158ba6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
         }
         #header1 {
         background-color:#60affe;
         color:#fff;
         text-align:center;
         padding:10px 0px;
         margin:auto;
         }
         #header2 {
         background-color:#8fc7fe;
         color:#fff; 
         text-align:center;
         padding:10px 0px;  
         margin:auto;         
         }
         #content {
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto;
         background-color:#fafafa;
         border:1px solid #ddd; 
         }    
         #content-content {
         clear:both;
         padding:5%;
         }  
         #button-container {
         float:left;
         margin-top:15px;
         text-align:center;
         width:100%;
         }   
         .button {
         display:inline-block;
         margin:10px; 
         padding:10px;
         background-color:#efefef;
         border:1px solid #ccc;
         border-radius:2px;
         color:#555;
         max-width:220px;
         min-width:220px;
         }         
         .search {
         display:inline-block; 
         }
         .search_box {
         margin:10px; 
         padding:10px;
         border:1px solid #ccc;
         border-radius:2px;
         max-width:220px;
         min-width:220px;  
         color:#555;
         font-family:'Helvetica Neue';
         font-size:110%;
         line-height:140%; 
         font-weight:200;   
         }
         @media (min-width: 1024px) {
         #header1 { width:50%; }
         #header2 { width:50%; }
         #content { width:50%; }            
         }
         @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1023px) {
         #header1 { width:80%; }
         #header2 { width:80%; }
         #content { width:80%; }            
         }
         @media (max-width: 767px) {
         #header1 { width:100%; }
         #header2 { width:100%; }
         #content { width:100%; }            
         body { font-size:140%; }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header1">Header 1</div>
      <div id="header2">Header 2</div>
      <div id="content">
         <div id="button-container">
            <div class="button">
               Button 1
            </div>
            <div class="search">
               <input class="search_box" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="content-content">
            <p> 
               Etiam at purus id ipsum sodales vehicula. Nam purus nunc, luctus ut laoreet et, pharetra eget est. Nulla 
               nisi tellus, euismod vel hendrerit dignissim, egestas eget ante. Morbi pellentesque, tellus ut adipiscing 
               vestibulum, purus orci gravida felis, sit amet rhoncus quam nulla non massa. Sed volutpat porttitor lectus 
               accumsan hendrerit. Donec lectus urna, euismod ut accumsan ac, congue in risus.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.search_box {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    max-width: 220px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    min-width: 220px;
    color: #555;
    height: 24px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-weight: 200;
}
```

and why this div around the search box? It's not the best practice to have a div element inline with something else.

Set the font-size: 110%; to the button as well.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work if you zoom the browser and/or resize the viewport. This is a prototype for a responsive website and I need the button and search box to match at any zoom level and any viewport.

Comment: I changed `font-size` to 100% on `.search_box` and removed the `div` around the search box. I think that's pretty much done it. Thanks for the hints.